# Windows: npm install express gives tunneling error

Tags: node.js, proxy, cmd, npm

I'm in Windows 7 ( Administrator) behind a proxy. I'm trying to: "npm install express" on the cmd terminal. I'm getting the following errors, What do I do?

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm config set proxy http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080


C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install express
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=4272:error:140
770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.
c:795:
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the error message?

Comment: I added proxy, Could you suggest what else I should do?